# Cannot addAll a sequence of instances of a protobuf auto-generated class

Tags: java, scala, protocol-buffers

I have two protobuf messages, which

```
message A {
    ...
}

message B {
    repeated A hoge = 1;
}
```

and protoc generates Java code:

```
public Builder addAllA(java.lang.Iterable<? extends A> values) {
    ...
}
```

But Scala codes bellow result in Type mismatch, expected: Iterable[_ <: A], actual: Iterable[A]

```
B.newBuilder().addAllA(A.newBuilder().build().toIterable)
```

How can I addAllA?

Answer (score 1):

For my simplified example this worked, so at least you can try:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

B.newBuilder().addAllA(A.newBuilder().build().toIterable.asJava)
```

From my PoV the error arises because of invariance of java Iterable and scala covariance type check, but not sure.

Comment: The error messages when java and scala have a type with the same (unqualified) name are so frustrating!